# Setting RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

Is it possible to set the `ValidationExpression` of a `RegularExpressionValidator` using JavaScript? I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.

Here's why I want to do this...

On a payment page I have a `DropDownList` that allows my user to select their card type. Beneath that is a `TextBox` in which they type their card number.

I want to use a `RegularExpressionValidator` to validate that their card number is valid for their given card type. The card payment processing is performed manually in a different system, so I cannot rely on this to catch incorrect card details.

Therefore I need to use a different `ValidationExpression` for each card type. I would like to set the `ValidationExpression` using JavaScript, firing off the `DropDownList` onchange event.

My `DropDownList` is bound to an XML document:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCardType" runat="server"
    DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"
    DataSourceID="xdsCardTypes" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="(select)" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="xdsCardTypes" runat="server"
    DataFile="~/App_Data/PaymentCards.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Here's the XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PaymentCards>
  <PaymentCard Text="American Express" Value="AmericanExpress" RegEx="3[47](\d{13})"  />
  <PaymentCard Text="MasterCard" Value="MasterCard" RegEx="5[1-5](\d{14})" />
  <PaymentCard Text="Maestro" Value="Maestro" RegEx="(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|6761)\d{8,15}" />
  <PaymentCard Text="Visa" Value="Visa" RegEx="4(\d{15}|\d{12})" />
</PaymentCards>
```

In code-behind I'm creating a JavaScript function call and adding it to the onchange event of the `DropDownList`:

```
XDocument paymentCards = XDocument.Parse(xdsCardTypes.GetXmlDocument().InnerXml, LoadOptions.None);

List<string> regExes = paymentCards.Descendants("PaymentCard")
    .Select(pc => pc.GetAttribute("RegEx").Value).ToList();

string setRegExValidatorScript = string.Format("setRegExValidator('{0}', '{1}', {2});",
    ddlCardType.ClientID,
    txtCardNumber_RegularExpressionValidator.ClientID,
    regExes.ToJavaScriptArgumentList());

ddlCardType.AddAttribute("onchange", setRegExValidatorScript);
```

And in a referenced .js file I have the following:

```
function setRegExValidator(ddlCardTypeID, regExValidatorID, regExes)
{
    var regEx = regExes[$get(ddlCardTypeID).selectedIndex];

    var val = $get(regExValidatorID);

    // TODO: Set the ValidationExpression!
}
```

So my one missing link is the ability to set the `ValidationExpression` from JavaScript. Yes I could use a postback to achieve this, but that seems unnecessary.

(Suggestions on an alternate approach are also welcomed!)

Answer (score 1):

```
function setRegExValidator(ddlCardTypeID, regExValidatorID, regExes)
{
    var regEx = regExes[$get(ddlCardTypeID).selectedIndex];

    var val = $get(regExValidatorID);

    val['validationexpression'] = regEx;
}
```

*NB: You need to ensure that the card number is validated properly on the server-side too.*

Comment: Thanks Luke, however that doesn't seem to actually work. The validationexpression of the validator seems to get updated, but validation always fails.

Comment: @Richard, I've just tested this (well, something very similar) in IE, Firefox and Chrome and it works as expected. Do the regexes work correctly if you try them individually in a standard RegularExpressionValidator without any of the dynamic JavaScript stuff?

Comment: Many thanks for your thoroughness Luke! My RegExes are working fine if  I set them in the aspx file directly, not sure what's going on. After some thought though I decided to just do this in C# in a CustomValidator, as I was using one for other validation anyway.